# vmc not working after install caldecott

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry

I'm use this instruction for install caldecott http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html but after it vmc not worked:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- restclient (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.1.9/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.1.9/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/vmc-0.4.2/lib/vmc/plugin.rb:43:in `load_all'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/set.rb:194:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/set.rb:194:in `each_key'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/set.rb:194:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/vmc-0.4.2/lib/vmc/plugin.rb:42:in `load_all'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/vmc-0.4.2/bin/vmc:9
    from /usr/local/bin/vmc:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/vmc:19
```

How can I fix that?

For reproduce:

```
1. sudo gem install caldecott --no-rdoc --no-ri
2. sudo gem install tunnel-vmc-plugin
```

Comment: provide info on what exactly you did in more detail so others can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as vmc 0.4 is a new release, the documentation online is a little out of date. What you actually need to do is install rest-client, although this should really be a dependency on tunnel-vmc-plugin!

```
gem install rest-client
```

and you should be good to go!